# NavigationLink in List using isActive pushes the wrong row

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to use NavigationLink's isActive variable to pop back to the root view controller.

The problem I'm experiencing is that using isActive pushes the wrong row when clicking on a list item. Remove the isActive variable and everything works as expected.

[image]

Here's some example code for demonstration purposes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var activateNavigationLink: Bool = false

    var exampleData = ["a", "b", "c"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List(exampleData, id: \.self) { item in
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondView(item: item), isActive: $activateNavigationLink) {
                    
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondView

```
struct SecondView: View {
    
    var item: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

This is driving me nuts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `activateNavigationLink` is just a `Bool` in your code, if it is `true`, every `NavigationLink` will register as active in your `List`. Right now, this is manifesting as the last item (`C`) getting pushed each time.

Instead, you'd need some system to store *which* item is active and then translate that to a boolean binding for the `NavigationLink` to use.

Here's one possible solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var activeNavigationLink: String? = nil

    var exampleData = ["a", "b", "c"]
    
    func bindingForItem(item: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init {
            activeNavigationLink == item
        } set: { newValue in
            activeNavigationLink = newValue ? item : nil
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List(exampleData, id: \.self) { item in
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SecondView(item: item), isActive: bindingForItem(item: item)) {
                    
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx. I don't understand how the `bindingForItem` function works. Can you give me some more detail please?

Comment: Sure. The binding provides a get and a set. A different binding is generated for each item. On get, it checks to see if the active link is equal to the item — if so, it returns true, if not, false. On set, if the incoming value is true, it sets the active link to the item. If it’s false, it sets the active link (which is an optional) to nil.

Comment: Thanks. That works great although how would I pop back to root view programmatically in SecondView?

Comment: You can pass a Binding to activeNavigationLink to the child view and then set it to nil when you want to pop. Or, pass a closure to a function on the parent view that sets activeNavigationLink to true. Let me know if you need either of those written out and I can do that when back at my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use activeNavigationLink on main view it should be used with cellView

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var exampleData = ["a", "b", "c"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List(exampleData, id: \.self) { item in
                
               CellView(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CellView

```
struct CellView: View {
        
    @State private var activateNavigationLink: Bool = false
        var item: String
        
        var body: some View {
              NavigationLink(
                        destination: SecondView(item: item), isActive: $activateNavigationLink) {
                        
                        Text(item)
                    }
        }
    }
```

SecondView

```
struct SecondView: View {
    
    var item: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```